# Swift 2 - replacement for the deprecated function extend (Swiftache)

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, xcode7

I have Swiftache in my Swift 2 project, and after the Xcode 7 update, the following line is complaining (the error is there is no longer an extend method).

```
public func renderText(text: String) {
        if !renderable {
            return
        }


        _text.extend(text)
    }
```

So _text.extend(text) is the offending line. What could I replace it with?
What did the extend method even do, originally? I can't find an equivalent because I'm not familiar with the original method back when it worked in the older version of Xcode.

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what Swiftache is, but according to the Xcode 7 release notes, extend() has been replaced by appendContentsOf(). – You *did* read the release notes, didn't you?

Comment: No, I don't even know where the release notes are. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Xcode -> Help -> Release Notes.